# How to test an error response in angular's $httpBackend?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-mock

We are using angular 1.2.x (we have to due to IE8). We are testing with Karma and Jasmine. I want to test the behavior of my modules, in case the server responds with an error. According to the angular documentation, I should just simply prepare the $httpBackend mock like this (exactly as I'd expect):

```
authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', '/auth.py');

// Notice how you can change the response even after it was set
authRequestHandler.respond(401, '');
```

This is what I am doing in my test:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    keepSessionAliveService = $injector.get('keepSessionAliveService');
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $interval = $injector.get('$interval');
}));

(...)

describe('rejected keep alive request', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        spyOn(authStorageMock, 'get');
        spyOn(authStorageMock, 'set');

        $httpBackend.when('POST', keepAliveUrl).respond(500, '');

        keepSessionAliveService.start('sessionId');
        $interval.flush(90*60*1001);
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });

    it('should not add the session id to the storage', function() {
        expect(authStorageMock.set).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

But the test fails, because the mock function is being called and I can see in the code coverage that it never runs into the error function I pass to the §promise.then as second argument.

Apparently I am doing something wrong here. Could it have to with the older angular version we're using?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
   it("should receive an Ajax error", function() {
        spyOn($, "ajax").andCallFake(function(e) {
            e.error({});
        });

         var callbacks = {
            displayErrorMessage : jasmine.createSpy()
        };

        sendRequest(callbacks, configuration);
        expect(callbacks.displayErrorMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
```